# how to have finer control about which ports docker opens in iptables?

Tags: iptables, firewall, docker

I am using UFW for setting my firewall rules.

But docker keeps overridding them in iptables openning all ports that have been mapped from the containers to the host.

I want to  have access only to two ports in a docker container from outside but block access the other docker containers ports and allow only localhost access for them (after ssh tunnel).

Any solutions apart from iptables=false?

Comment: Don't EXPOSE them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to skip any iptables changes and publish ports you need to access from localhost to only the loopback interface. E.g.

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:2222:22 -d your_ssh_image
```

This would only publish the port 2222 to the 127.0.0.1 interface, and not all interfaces (0.0.0.0).

---

If you really need to modify the iptables rules in a way that impacts docker containers, use the `DOCKER-USER` table, as [documented by docker](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/), e.g.:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 ! -s 192.168.1.1 -j DROP
```